# The structure of the Fae courts

Tags: welsh, irish, fairies, scottish

I'm looking for the structure of the Fairy (Fae) courts which are defined by Seelie or Unseelie alignments.
There is a lot of fiction written but the problem is that they twist it to their own purposes and add things not in the original mythologies.
Can anyone point to a definitive taxonomy (Scottish, Welsh, Irish) that covers this?
Regards

Comment: There isn't much.  Indeed, Katherine Briggs discussed the possibility that it was all a literary trope that sometimes contaminated the folklore.

Comment: I was looking for info because I am writing fantasy and wanted to include a fae court scene in it. I had a scenario and wanted to play it through based on what I could determine from their rules and how to get around them. I guess I'll have to color between the lines a bit more than I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sanderson, Stewart F (December 1957). "The Present State of Folklore Studies in Scotland", may answer your question.  The one thing I believe is universal in the two courts is matriarchal leaders, Banrionacha, or “Queens”. Otherwise. I can only think of fictional literary works referencing any structure of their “courts”, if any exist at all in scholarly works.